# VBA Userform Single Sheet Linked Inventory Entries

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet/userform that I am making for inventory purposes.

The first function of my userform is to take data for a connector and a mate from my textboxes on the form, and put it on my sheet in the rows/cells I tell it to. That code works fine.

The second function is to cross-reference the connector and the mate, so that when I either search or change the parts' data I have up-to-date information.
I do this by storing the cell addresses in Row 1 upon connector and mate creation. Then when I hit "confirm" the addresses are copied to specified cells within their own rows with the "=" sign added, to create reference formulas.

One row in the sheet is for connectors with mate references after it, the next row is for Mates with connector references after it. Then I move on to the next rows and do it again.

I can only do this with one pair of part numbers, and with no other part numbers after that. 
What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
    Private Sub XREFCONFIRM1_Click()

    Dim iRow1 As Long
    Dim iRow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("1STDRAFT")
    row_number = 4

    iRow1 = ws.Cells.Find(What:=PART1.Text, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

    iRow2 = ws.Cells.Find(What:=PART2.Text, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

        row_number = row_number + 1

        item_in_review = Sheets("1STDRAFT").Range("A" & row_number).Value

    With ws
       If item_in_review = PART1.Text Then

      .Cells(iRow1, 15).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 15).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 16).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 16).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 17).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 17).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 18).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 18).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 19).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 19).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 20).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 20).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 21).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 21).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 22).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 22).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 23).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 23).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 24).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 24).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 25).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 25).Value

     'With ws
            'If item_in_review = PART2.Text Then
      .Cells(iRow2, 15).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 1).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 16).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 2).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 17).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 3).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 18).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 5).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 19).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 8).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 20).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 9).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 21).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 10).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 22).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 11).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 23).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 12).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 24).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 13).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 25).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 14).Value

            End If
        End With


    End Sub
```

Drive Folder Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz4rZ9ZqoU0tbkdaQjBBZVgyRTA?usp=sharing

File Direct Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4rZ9ZqoU0tVmJKa0xlUXBNcGc/view?usp=sharing

Photo Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tzi_2gaaXypBen2Ls7p21USat8uS_qhcRDwmGQLCcXE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This bit `row_number = row_number + 1` makes it look like you intended this to be a loop, but never made it one. Hence, it only runs once for one part number, then stops.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for seeing that! I just added "Do" above my Row_number and "Loop Until Item_In_Review = """ after my End With statement, and that cleared it all up!
Thanks again man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now how my code looks, for anyone wanting to know. I will update the links I have provided in a few, to help anyone that wants use my forms.

```
   Private Sub XREFCONFIRM1_Click()

    Dim iRow1 As Long
    Dim iRow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("1STDRAFT")
    row_number = 4

    iRow1 = ws.Cells.Find(What:=PART1.Text, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

    iRow2 = ws.Cells.Find(What:=PART2.Text, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

    Do  
    row_number = row_number + 1

        item_in_review = Sheets("1STDRAFT").Range("A" & row_number).Value

    With ws
       If item_in_review = PART1.Text Then

      .Cells(iRow1, 15).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 15).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 16).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 16).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 17).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 17).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 18).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 18).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 19).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 19).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 20).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 20).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 21).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 21).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 22).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 22).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 23).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 23).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 24).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 24).Value
      .Cells(iRow1, 25).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 25).Value

     'With ws
            'If item_in_review = PART2.Text Then
      .Cells(iRow2, 15).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 1).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 16).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 2).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 17).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 3).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 18).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 5).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 19).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 8).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 20).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 9).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 21).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 10).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 22).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 11).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 23).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 12).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 24).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 13).Value
      .Cells(iRow2, 25).Value = "=" & Sheets("1STDRAFT").Cells(1, 14).Value

            End If
        End With
          Loop Until item_in_review = ""

    End Sub
```